# I am trying to redirect via react- router-dom when my function submits but i keep getting this error

Tags: function, redirect, react-router-dom

I want my route to change when I submit the form but I am getting an error I am also trying to prevent default. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. i have been googling for hours. i would like to redirect to /searchProducts

```
×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/Test/Documents/GitHub/Ecommerce-Store/src/components/searchBar.js:10
   7 |  const { search } = productConsumer;
   8 | 
   9 |  useEffect(() => {
> 10 |    console.log(this.props.history);
     | ^  11 |  });
  12 | 
  13 |  const onChange = e => {
```

```
    import React, { useContext, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
    import { ProductContext } from '../../src/context';

    const ProductFilter = props => {
      const productConsumer = useContext(ProductContext);
      const text = useRef('');
      const { search } = productConsumer;

      useEffect(() => {
        console.log(this.props.history);
      });

      const onChange = e => {
        if (text.current.value !== '') {
          search(e.target.value);
        } else {
        }
      };

      const onSubmit = e => {
        // e.preventDefault();
        // this.props.history.push('/path');
      };

      return (
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit()}>
          <input
            ref={text}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search Keywords..."
            onChange={onChange}
            id=""
          />
        </form>
      );
    };

    export default ProductFilter;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work with `history` object you need a [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter) HOC.

Wrap your component with HOC and you can access `history` object.

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const ProductFilter = props => {
   ...
   useEffect(() => {
     console.log(props.history);   //Don't use this
   });

   const onSubmit = e => {
     // e.preventDefault();
     props.history.push('/path');  //Now you can access history object.
   };
   ...
}

export default withRouter(ProductFilter);
```

**Note:** In functional component, we don't have access to `this`.

Comment: You are directly invoking function on load `<form onSubmit={onSubmit()}>` you need t do this, `<form onSubmit={onSubmit}>`